# Куда сохранить свои функции для терминала?

Tags: linux, функции, bash

Мне приходиться работать с разными серверами на linux, подключаюсь по ssh.
И часто приходиться делать разную рутинную работу через консоль.

Я создал себе рабочий файл (.sh), где собрал написанные функции.
Вот самый простой пример:

```
cdl() { 
   cd "$@" && ls -la; 
}
```

и этот файл с функциями, кидаю в рабочую директорию из проекта в проект и перед подключением к проекту всегда запускаю этот файл, чтобы функции подключились.

Можно ли куда-то в ядро или еще куда-то записать эти функции, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз запускать этот файл, а просто записать эти функции в какой-то файл, который будет автоматически видеть мои функции?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` или `~/.bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 3):

если речь только о программе *bash* и только об интерактивных сеансах, то подходящим местом для ваших собственных функций будет файл `~/.bashrc`.

можно либо добавить код функций непосредственно в этот файл:

```
$ cat ~/мои.функции | ssh пользователь@машина 'cat >> ~/.bashrc'
```

либо добавить только вызов этого файла (скопировав и сам файл):

```
$ scp ~/мои.функции пользователь@машина:
$ ssh пользователь@машина 'echo "if [ -f ~/мои.функции ]; then . ~/мои.функции; fi" >> ~/.bashrc'
```

Answer (score 1):

разделить функции на файлы
**cdl.sh**

```
cdl() { 
   cd "$@" && ls -la; 
}

#запуск функции
cdl
```

и можно сделать ссылку в папку **bin**

```
sudo ln -s -r cdl.sh   /bin/cdl
```

и вызывать так

```
bash cdl
```

или

```
chmod  -R +x cdl.sh
```

и можно вызывать так

```
cdl
```

еще можете изучить такую тему как `bash переменные окружения PATCH`

но если не хотите делить функции на файлы , добавьте ***"$@"***

**myFun.sh**

```
cdl() { 
   cd "$@" && ls -la; 
}
cd2() { 
   cd "$@" && ls -la; 
}

  "$@"
```

потом

```
sudo ln -s -r myFun.sh   /bin/myFun
chmod  -R +x myFun.sh
```

и вызывайте так

~$: `myFun cdl`

~$: `myFun cd2`

Comment: `sudo ln -s -r myFun.sh   /bin/myFun`


вместо этого можно просто положить в /etc/profile.d